# Cordova Phonegap "Export Failed" error code 70 While building ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-cli

I am currently using Cordova Phonegap to build an application for iOS. It was working fine, but now I'm getting an error when I'm running `cordova build ios` in the terminal.

I'm getting the following error:

> ** EXPORT FAILED **
>
> Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,RoastBot.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/JarrodMorgan/Desktop/RoastBot/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/JarrodMorgan/Desktop/RoastBot/platforms/ios/build/device

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issues...

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by Xcode 9 expecting certain values in exportOptions.plist located in the path that is displayed in the error message. In your case it is `,/Users/JarrodMorgan/Desktop/RoastBot/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist`.

Here is how `exportOptions.plist` looks for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>TEAM_ID_GOES_HERE</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
      <key>YOUR_BUNDLE_ID</key>
      <string>PROVISIONIG_PROFILE_UUID_WOULD_BE_HERE</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iPhone Developer</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Double check that you have `provisioningProfiles` and `signingStyle` values in your `exportOptions.plist` if you don't then you probably have `cordova-ios` version prior to `4.5.2`. This was fixed and released in `cordova-ios 4.5.2` please see this [PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/338)

In order for your to resolve this error update your `cordova-ios` to `4.5.2` or later, drop your plugins and platforms and re-add them.

However in my case after upgrading to `cordova-ios 4.5.4` I started to see following error:

```
ld: 270 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It turns out that that was caused by the fact that `cordova` built `cordova-plugin-console` into its core and if you have that plugin in your project than you might get the above error. Simply remove `cordova-plugin-console` and this error will go away. Here is what it says on console plugin's github page:

> This plugin is no longer being worked on as the functionality provided
>   by this plugin is now included in cordova-ios 4.5.0 or greater, and
>   support is already built in to cordova-windows > 5.0.0. You should
>   remove this plugin from your applications.

Here is the [link to the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Doesn't this file get generated on the fly thus reverting all manual changes?

Comment: `exportOptions.plist` is automatically generated yes. The solution for me here was remove `cordova-plugin-console`

Comment: Removing and re-adding the platform solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by returning to the old PhoneGap version.
Add this to your config.xml file

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.1" />
```

Comment: For some people downgrading is not an option. Please see my explanation below how to fix this.